# Cubejs Error during upload of pre-aggregation: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, cube

I've been trying to use pre-aggregations with a default setup of cubejs using the docker compose setup: https://cube.dev/docs/getting-started/docker/compose

I am however encountering the same error with all pre-aggregations (this is just one sample, however one exists for all pre-aggregations I try):

```
Error: Error during upload of dev_pre_aggregations.publishers_users_rollup_2yhuuedy_kidftr4f_1ht5m0r-0.csv.gz create table: CREATE TABLE dev_pre_aggregations.<redacted>: Internal: No such file or directory (os error 2
```

Where my cubes look like this:

```
cube(`Users`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM users`,
  
  preAggregations: {
    users_rollup: {
      type: 'rollup',
      dimensions: [CUBE.id, CUBE.email]
    }
  },
  
  joins: {
    
  },
  
  measures: {
    count: {
      type: `count`,
    }
  },
  
  dimensions: {
    id: {
      sql: `id`,
      type: `number`,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    
    email: {
      sql: `email`,
      type: `string`
    }
  },
  
  dataSource: `default`
});

cube(`Publishers`, {
    extends: Users,
    sql: `SELECT * FROM ${Users.sql}`,
});

cube(`Statistics`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM impressions`,
  
  preAggregations: {
    statistics_by_publisher_rollup: {
      type: 'rollup',
      measures: [CUBE.impressions],
      dimensions: [CUBE.publisherId],
      timeDimension: CUBE.date,
      granularity: `day`
    },
    statistics_with_publishers_rollup: {
      type: `rollupJoin`,
      measures: [CUBE.impressions],
      dimensions: [CUBE.publisherId, Publishers.email],
      rollups: [Publishers.users_rollup, CUBE.statistics_by_publisher_rollup]
    }
  },
  
  joins: {
    Publishers: {
      relationship: `belongsTo`,
      sql: `${CUBE.advertiserId} = ${Publishers.id}`
    }
  },
  
  measures: {
    impressions: {
      sql: `impressions`,
      type: `sum`,
    }
  },
  
  dimensions: {
    date: {
      sql: `date`,
      type: `time`
    },

    publisherId: {
      sql: `publisher_id`,
      type: `number`,
      primaryKey: true
    },
  },
  
  dataSource: `statistics`
});
```

I see the `temp-uploads` in the `.cubestore/data` directory but thats about it.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here in the same configuration. I removed the "preAggregations" key from the schemas that were causing this issue. Clearly not ideal but it works as a temporary fix.
As I understand it, the main purpose of pre-aggregation is to improve performance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).